# how can i access remote server json/html data in my phonegap project?

Tags: cordova

In my phone gap project I need to access json / html data from a remote server .I tried with Xmlhttprequest,but it is not working.It will be helpful if somebody helped me.Thanks in advance.

Note: I am using phone gap with php

Comment: `Note: I am using phone gap with php` Are you trying to run php on your device? Or are you making ajax calls to a php script on a server?

Comment: No no I am not trying to run php. I just want to execute a php script on a remote server and want to display the result in my app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is some code that I use for making connections to a REST style API (uses jquery):

```
var api = {
    connection: {
        baseUrl: 'your_domain.tld',
        apiUrl: '/some_path/'
    },
    initialize: function() {
        api.setupAjaxDefaults();
    },
    setupAjaxDefaults: function() {
        var headers = {
            'Accept': "application/json; encoding='utf-8'",
            'Content-Type': "application/json; encoding='utf-8'"
        };
        $.ajaxSetup({
            headers: headers,
            dataType: 'json',
            crossDomain: true
        });
    },
    testCall: function(data) {
        api.ajaxGet( someMethod, data, aSuccessCallback, anErrorCallback );
    },
    ajaxGet: function(methodName, data, successCallback, errorCallback) {
        $.ajax({
            url: api.connection.baseUrl + api.connection.apiUrl + methodName,
            data: data,
            cache: false,
            type: 'GET',
            success: function(result, status, xhr) {
                if ($.isFunction(successCallback)) {
                    successCallback(result);
                }
            },
            error: function() {
                if ($.isFunction(errorCallback)) {
                    errorCallback();
                }
            }

        });
    },
    ajaxGetCached: function(methodName, data, successCallback, errorCallback) {
        $.ajax({
            url: api.connection.baseUrl + api.connection.apiUrl + methodName,
            data: data,
            type: 'GET',
            success: function(result, status, xhr) {
                if ($.isFunction(successCallback)) {
                    successCallback(result);
                }
            },
            error: function() {
                if ($.isFunction(errorCallback)) {
                    errorCallback();
                }
            }

        });
    }
};
```

To use this, You first call `api.initialize();`

Then to make a call (example of testCall in place above):

```
api.testCall(someApiMethod, { data: someData, moreData: evenMore });
```