# CORS on phonegap not working

Tags: javascript, ajax, cordova, cors

I finally got the code working cross domain from my PC to my server via the browser. But moving the code to phonegap it's not working anymore. I've given permission for internet and access origin * so it should be able to access all webpages. What else do I need to enable?

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="js/jquery-1.11.0.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.css" />
<script>
    function dologin() {
        var senddata = $('#form').serialize();
        alert(senddata);

        $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: 'XXXXXXXX',
            data: senddata,
            crossDomain: true,
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(response) {
                if(response.success == true)
                    alert("YAY");
                else
                    alert("NAY");
            },
            error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {      
                console.log("Status: " + textStatus); alert("Error: " + errorThrown);
            } 
        });
        return false;
    };
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Logg inn</h1>
    <form id="form" onsubmit="return dologin();">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="email">Epost</label> <input type="email"
                class="form-control" name="email" value="test@test.no"
                placeholder="Epost">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="password">Passord</label> <input type="password"
                class="form-control" name="password" value="test"
                placeholder="Passord">
        </div>
        <div class="checkbox">
            <label> <input type="checkbox" name="remember_me">
                Husk meg
            </label>
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Logg inn</button>
    </form>

    <div class="login-help">
        <p>
            Glemt passordet? <a href="index.html">Trykk her for å endre det</a>.
        </p>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: In which platform you are trying? Android or IOS?

Comment: @ConnectingCode: It's android

Comment: What exactly you are getting in error part?

Comment: @ConnectingCode: I'm getting Error "Not found" in the alert. I had the same error on PC until i added some line that enabled CORS on the server.

Comment: see my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22970648/how-can-i-access-remote-server-json-html-data-in-my-phonegap-project/22971218#22971218

Answer (score 0):

Try including this line in ajax call

```
headers: { "cache-control": "no-cache" }
```

Comment: The url you are hitting is http or https?

Comment: Just regular http with a php behind processing the stuff (Laravel framework)

Comment: In browser it is working fine right? So check if there is any issue in internet connectivity of that mobile.

Comment: Cross-domain policy does not apply to PhoneGap (for a variety of reasons, basically because your app is essentially running off the file:// URI on-device). So you try by removing those.

Comment: It's working fine in the browser on my PC. But I couldn't understand what you meant by ur last post, removing what?

Answer (score 0):

Cross-domain policy does not apply to PhoneGap (for a variety of reasons, basically because your app is essentially running off the file:// URI on-device). So you try by removing the cross domain parameter in ajax call.